# Is there a way to delete object from Array in Java?

Tags: java

I'm working on a board game. I have an array of objects
Player[] player, let's say player[0], player[1], player[2]. If player[1] finishes a game first, other players continue to play. I need cycle for to skip this player's index. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: You'd need to recreate the array. Better use ArrayList or even better LinkedList.

Comment: I would rather use dynamic array for example List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array is not a dynamic data structure, where you can add or remove an item in an easy way.

You should use a collection, like a `List` or an `ArrayList` or even a `LinkedList`, for example. The list data structures are much easier to use and mantain, because they've methods that let you add/remove or find your items.

For example, in a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html), you can add a new item or remove an existing one, in this way:

```
List<MyType> myList = new ArrayList<MyType>(); //creation of List
MyType myObject = new MyType(); //creation of the object you want to add to the list

myList.add(myObject); //to add your item

myList.remove(myObject); //to remove your item
```

Comment: `List` is an interface. You cannot instantiate it directly. =)

Answer (score 3):

Use a `List` for this. You can `remove` and `add` to a `List`.

```
List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot remove from an array. Maximum you can do is making that is `null`

```
player[1]= null;
```

Your best bet is to go for a [`List Interface`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html).

P.s `Arrays` usage was limited after the introduction of [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dynamic 'array' like `ArrayList`.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("John");
list.add("Doe");
list.add("Foo Bar");
System.out.println(list.size()); // Expands
list.remove(0);
System.out.println(list.size()); // Shrinks
```

You can run the example here and see the output: http://ideone.com/ciDSwa

So, in your context, you can do as follows:

```
List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
// add players
// remove players
```

The term 'expands' and 'shrinks' should be taken with a grain of salt because it only expands if the number of objects goes beyond a certain threshold. After that, the contents of the `ArrayList` are copied to a new location in the memory.

Comment: I don't think that suggesting `Vector` is a good idea since it is kind of obsolete these days.

Comment: Rather use phase "dynamic array". This is i think better and more suitable name.

Answer (score 0):

To allow such removing of items, its best to use Lists which will allow both add and remove conveniently. In arrays, you cannot remove an item, but you could set the value to null and check if the value is null when iterating.